# why do I get the shearmode instaed of the edit mode. bl3.4/3.5

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

When I select a point in edit mode I come in the shear modus. Cannot select points are surfaces. So when I click on a point, the shear symbols appears.

Comment: Use 'T' key and select the top icon to come back to select mode.

Comment: Please add an image of your Blender screen to your question so that we can see what you're talking about. In Blender, Window > Save Screenshot then follow this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post.